# ¿Cómo insertar código php desde javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estamos en un proyecto de registro de visitantes y nos gustaría que nos expliquen cómo poder insertar código php desde javascript, mejor dicho como llenar un combobox haciendo una consulta sql desde javascript:

```js
//Funcion mostrar datos del visitante para ser actualizados

function datosVisitanteEditar(datos) {
  d = datos.split("||");
  $(idVisitanteEditar).val(d[0]);
  $(nombreVisitanteEditar).val(d[1]);
  $(apeliidosVisitanteEdiatar).val(d[2]);
  $(celularVisitanteEditar).val(d[3]);
  $(correoVisitanteEditar).val(d[4]);
  $("#tipoDocVisitanteEditar").html(`<option value="${d[5]}">${d[6]}</option>`);
  $(numDocVisitanteEditar).val(d[7]);
  $(direccVisitanteEditar).val(d[14]);
  $(obseVisitanteEdiatar).val(d[15]);
}
```

```html
<div class="col form-group">
  <label for="tipoDocVisitanteEditar">Seleccione tipo de documento</label>
  <select class="custom-select" id="tipoDocVisitanteEditar" name="tipoDocVisitanteEditar">

  </select>
</div>
```

```
<?php
                $sqltipodoc = "SELECT * FROM tipodocumento";
                $consultatipodoc = $conexion->query($sqltipodoc);
                while (
                  $valoresTipoDoc = mysqli_fetch_array($consultatipodoc)
                ) {
                  echo "<option value='" .
                    $valoresTipoDoc['id'] .
                    "'>" .
                    $valoresTipoDoc['tipo'] .
                    "</option>";
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: Hola @juan-castro has una solicitud ajax que te devuelva el conjunto de opciones debidamente formateado

Comment: La respuesta apropiada es `ajax`, pero, ¿Por qué no usas directamente `php`?. Bastaría con poner tu bloque de código `php` entre las etiquetas del `select`.

Comment: Solo comentar, que si hicieras eso que pides, la contrasenya de acceso al sql apareceria en el JavaScript, o sea, seria visible en el lado cliente, y entenderas que seria un fallo de seguridad muy grande.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada veo que estas trabajando con PHP, debes crear un script que te retorne los datos del combobox en JSON, un ejemplo seria el siguiente:

```
<?php
    $datos_combobox = array("fruta1" => "manzana", "fruta2" => 
    "guineo", "fruta3" => "naranja");
    //Procedemos a imprimir en JSON
    print_r(json_encode($datos_combobox));
?>
```

Esto al ejecutarlo te devolvera lo siguiente:

```
{"fruta1":"manzana","fruta2":"guineo","fruta3":"naranja"}
```

luego utilizas javascript para hacer una petición al servidor y llenar los datos de tu combobox

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ComboBox</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="mySelect">
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

y el javascript quedaría así:

```
fetch('https://example.com/myJson').then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
}).then(function(respuesta) {
  //Convertimos a JSON
  respuesta = JSON.parse(respuesta);
  //Renderizamos los datos en el select
  forEach(function (index, item) {
    let opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = index;
    opt.innerHTML = item;
            document.querySelector("#select").appendChild(opt);  
  });
});
```